# Zurb F5: Abide not validating iDevices, nothing valid on desktop

Tags: iphone, ipad, validation, zurb-foundation

Using Foundation 5 Abide, I have

```
<form data-abide>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern="alpha" required />
</form>
```

And at the end of the page just before the body close tag I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation('abide', 'events');
</script>
```

On my desktop PC, no matter what I enter in the input field, the Abide tooltip pops up saying it's not valid. On the iPad and iPhone, it doesn't validate anything - just submits no matter what. Anyone else run into this?